# I need a midi player for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, midi

I was able to config Timidity to play classical midis, but for others midis the classical configuration does not works.

I know VLC plays midi, but needs soundfount configuration.

I would like to find a light and good software to play midi.

Soundfount support is not necessary, but it is appreciable.

Comment: I found one that serves me, folks. It is called BZRPlayer. http://bzrplayer.blazer.nu/ and the twitter account also: https://twitter.com/BZRPlayer

Answer (score 3):

[foobar 2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/), in addition to being a extremely configurable music player and lightweight, has a [midi](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_midi) plugin which in my experience works pretty well, with almost no config (short of downloading the plugin to the right folder)

Comment: +1 for foobar 2000 which I would also consider 'light and good software' as requested by the OP!

Comment: Thanks, it also works and foobar has the Portable version: http://portableappz.blogspot.com/2011/08/foobar2000-118-beta-6-117.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use Winamp 2.80 if you want a player to play your *.mid files. You don't need to use the last version of Winamp. This one is too heavy if you need just a player to play simple *.mid files. Try it. You only need to download it. This can be done easily.

Comment: I have WinAmp Portable installed, but it is bloated. I use it just for tags work. http://portableappz.blogspot.com/2011/07/winamp-5623173-pro-full-multilingual.html

Answer (score 0):

I also use wv_player.exe to play my midis in command line. You can use this player which can be easily downloaded to play your midi files. Unzip it and put a copy of the ewxecutable - wv_player.exe - in C:\windows folder. So you go to the Command Prompt of Windows 7 and open the folder where you midis are, write wv_player.exe at the prompt and listen to your midis.

Comment: it might help to link to this software, rather than expecting people to look for it. Also, you can post both answers together i believe.

Comment: Awesome. Terrific. It played a common midi in sleek time. Thanks a lot. http://www.webxpace.com/software/